# delphi a fast way to convert hex string to binary string

Tags: delphi

I have to convert a hex string to a binary string like this

```
"F" -> "‭1111‬"
"A" -> "‭1010‬"
"1AF1" -> "1101011110001"
```

I have this function:

```
function HexToBin(Hexadecimal: string): string;
const
  BCD: array [0..15] of string =
    ('0000', '0001', '0010', '0011', '0100', '0101', '0110', '0111',
    '1000', '1001', '1010', '1011', '1100', '1101', '1110', '1111');
var
  i: integer;
begin
  Result := '';
  for i := Length(Hexadecimal) downto 1 do
    Result := BCD[StrToInt('$' + Hexadecimal[i])] + Result;
end;
```

and I call it like this:

```
for I := 0 to Trunc(tcpFrame.Length/100) do
begin
   str := copy(tcpFrame , (I*100)+1 , 100  );
   data  := data +  HexToBin( str );
end;
```

but this is really slow on large data like 50-60 MB of string

Is there a better and faster way for this?

Comment: Doesn't seem related to hex or binary. Surely this is just about concatenating strings. Preallocate the string. You know how long it is. Then fill out the characters using that hex to bin lookup table.

Comment: Is there a reason you have such a huge amount of binary data stored as hexadecimal text?  Sometimes when you're optimizing it's useful to take a step back and make a change two steps behind you to avoid having to deal with something cumbersome later.  If you can avoid hex as text altogether that should probably be the preferred solution.

Comment: @J... i receive  some captured image data from a radio transmitter as bytes then convert them to a Hex string.i must convert these to a binary string and find a sync-word to show the image.now image is showing but the process speed is low ,im trying to speed up each part of application.i dont know is it possible to find a 40 bit sync-word in a array of bytes,so i used the solution above!

Comment: @peimanF. I've never heard of a radio that transmits large binary images encoded as hex text.  Why does it do that?  Did you make it do that, or is this someone else's bad idea?  I'm still curious about where and why this design decision came from.

Comment: @J... this is a bit complicated :) but hardware's are pre-build,i must match with them.

Comment: @peimanF. I'm asking because there may very well be a better solution overall than what you're doing depending on what your data is and where it is coming from.  It's never a good idea to reinvent the wheel and it sounds like that may be happening.  Is this astronomical FITS data? Where does it come from?

Comment: image data com from a radio then a receiver grab them and send to me with a tcp connection.i get data from tcp in bytes `AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadBytes(data2, 1099, False);` then i convert them to bits to find sync-word.i dont know is it possible to find sync-word in bytes directly or no,this is the reason i used this solution.the main problem is my coming data is bits and sync word is `Ac543265fc` (1010110001010100001100100110010111111100).

Comment: @peimanF. Well, yes, you should be able to make all of these comparisons directly - converting to a binary string for a comparison is painfully slow and entirely unnecessary.  It would be worth posting a follow up question explaining your actual problem, showing in detail the format of the data you are receiving and what you are looking for.  There will be a much better way to do what you want.

Comment: For sure you are doing this completely wrong by using hex or binary strings.

Comment: @J... thank you.i got my answer here.for decode the image i will send a new question ASAP.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe the main problem is that you append to the string one part at a time.

In Delphi, building a dynamic array or string by adding a single small part at a time is very slow. A better approach is to pre-allocate the array/string to a large size and then fill its contents. If you know the final length at the beginning, use this size; otherwise, allocate in large chunks.

In this case, we do know the final length.

A sample implementation of this idea:

```
function HexStrToBinStr(const AHexStr: string): string;
var
  i, j: Integer;
const
  HexParts: array[0..$F] of string =
    (
      {0} '0000',
      {1} '0001',
      {2} '0010',
      {3} '0011',
      {4} '0100',
      {5} '0101',
      {6} '0110',
      {7} '0111',
      {8} '1000',
      {9} '1001',
      {A} '1010',
      {B} '1011',
      {C} '1100',
      {D} '1101',
      {E} '1110',
      {F} '1111'
    );
begin
  SetLength(Result, 4 * AHexStr.Length);
  j := 1;
  for i := 1 to AHexStr.Length do
  begin
    case AHexStr[i] of
      '0'..'9':
        Move(HexParts[Ord(AHexStr[i]) - Ord('0')][1], Result[j], sizeof(char) * 4);
      'A'..'F':
        Move(HexParts[$A + Ord(AHexStr[i]) - Ord('A')][1], Result[j], sizeof(char) * 4);
      'a'..'f':
        Move(HexParts[$A + Ord(AHexStr[i]) - Ord('a')][1], Result[j], sizeof(char) * 4);
    else
      raise EConvertError.CreateFmt('Invalid hexadecimal string "%s".', [AHexStr]);
    end;
    Inc(j, 4);
  end;
end;
```

The fact that I don't compute your intermediate `'$' + Hexadecimal[i]` string and call `StrToInt` might also speed things up a bit.

**Bonus exercise**: As a bonus exercise, modify this code by adding a parameter `APrettyPrint: Boolean = False` that, if `True`, adds a space between each group of four bits. Of course you should still preallocate.